# How Open a text file with bytes and show result in PyQT GUI

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt5, txt

i've been trying to work on a gui that receives a text file in bytes and show the values in the text editor.

I've tried this-

```
#Get the filename of the file to be uploaded
def get_filename(self):
    caption = ""  # Empty uses default caption.
    initial_dir = ""  # Empty uses current folder.
    initial_filter = FILE_FILTERS[3]  # Select one from the list.
    filters = ";;".join(FILE_FILTERS)
    print("Filters are:", filters)
    print("Initial filter:", initial_filter)

    filename, selected_filter = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
        self.mainWindow,
        caption=caption,
        directory=initial_dir,
        filter=filters,
        initialFilter=initial_filter,
          
    )
    #self.ui.lineEdit.setText(filename)####Opening thr selected file
    if filename:
        with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
            text = file.read()
            self.textEdit.toPlainText(text)
            file.close()
```

and this -

```
def file_open(self):
    name = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open File')
    file = open(name,'r')

    self.editor()

    with file:
        text = file.read()
        self.textEdit.setText(text)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhoWy.png)

i need parameters like this from the bytes
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EUc6.png)

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Are you trying to create something like a hex editor? If you need to show the raw byte values, how do you want them to be displayed? And how do you want to handle line-ending characters?

Comment: @ekhumoro, Technically the raw byte values are all i need to be displayed.
Updated the question to show what it's showing exactly.
THere are no errors, it justs opens a text Qtexteditor without the data.

Comment: Sure, but bytes aren't *text*, so you can't just dump them in a *text*-editor and expect sane results. And to repeat: how *exactly* do you want the values to be displayed? For example, what do you expect a null-byte to look like?

Comment: To be honest i'm no really sure i understand the question how  do i want expect a null byte to look like.
The data comes from reading parameters from a embedded device with objects that was downloaded. 

I have to show the parameters in a text file. 
I tried the Decode the byte string and turn it in to a character using .decode(), but no results. i'm reallystuck

Comment: Why do you want to view the bytes at all? What do you expect to see? Is this just a question of curiosity, or do you have some specific purpose in mind?

Comment: The bytes come from a dive. it should have data like : DeviceID Frequency etc

Comment: @ekhumoro, i added a photo to show what exactly im looking for

Comment: So you don't, in fact, want to view the bytes at all. What exactly is this file? How was it generated, and what file-extension does it have?

Comment: @MikexCodes 1. your first code is wrong, as [`toPlainText()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#toPlainText) is a *getter* and obviously doesn't accept any argument (also, `file.close()` is useless using `with`); 2. your second code is insufficient, as we don't know what `editor()` does and, for what we know, you could be replacing the editor without knowing; 3. are you able to open that file with a plain text editor (like notepad) and see its contents?

Comment: @ekhumoro, i specified the data type i was looking for. 
There were 2 options either as a .bin file or a . txt file . i saved it as a bin file.

The file came from a download of object parameters from a hardware. My task is to download the object parameters to a file. and then show it's parameters to a file. Its from an IOT device meaning it's in binary.

Comment: Why didn't you just choose to save it as a text file?!

Comment: @musicamante I'm able to open the file in a regular text editor, but you can se it's in binary

Comment: @ekhumoro, apologies the file is saved in a .txt file

Comment: @ekhumoro, so that's what the dilemma is. I'm not able to convert the binary data to human readable form

Comment: Well, it may use a different text-encoding than your system default. Try something like `open(name, 'r', encoding='utf-8')`. Or if that doesn't work, try `'utf-8-sig'`, `'latin1'` or `'cp1256'`. What was the specific program you used to create the file?

Comment: Just to be clear: which of the two options did you select? Did you select `.bin` and save it ***as a text file***? Or did you choose `.txt`? You really need to make sure you select `.txt` and save it as a text file.

Comment: i used .txt for it

Comment: Unfortunately i'm going to have to access all the objects manually and pritnt them